# Cocoa - Get element that had focus before an action

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I have a Window with multiple `NSTableView` elements where I can select rows.
Now when I press a button an action is triggered and I need to do stuff depending on which element in which `NSTableView` was selected before the click.
How do I do this?
I can check using the `selectedRowIndexes` but this is set for all tableViews that has selected items and not only for the one that the user wants the action for. (the last one that was selected)

Comment: Whenever a row is selected, store the info you need from that cell in a property. Then you can use that for your button action.

Comment: Is the button inside the table view? Does the click or the action change the selection? Is the question "How do I get the currently focused table view?"?

Comment: The button is somewhere in the App and has no connection to the TableView. The TableView is a standard TableView that can be clicked. The action just has to read the selection of the TableViews. The solution from @koen seems to be reasonable

Comment: Will this solution work when you click on the selected row of another table view? You can get the focused table view from `window.firstResponder` and its `superview`s.

Comment: Actually the solution I tried first did not work as expected as a click on an empty space inside the table will not trigger the "store the cell in property". The window.firstResponder trick works perfectly fine. Thanks @Willeke